# Ошибка во время Deploy (Heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku

Всем привет

Я использую готовый скрипт "[VK2Discord](https://github.com/MrZillaGold/VK2Discord)" от автора "MrZillaGold" и пытаюсь загрузить его на "Heroku", но во время установки получаю ошибку:

```
Enumerating objects: 28, done.
Counting objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 62.58 KiB | 7.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 28 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=15.0.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version >=15.0.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.5.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 7.19.1
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:
remote:        added 246 packages, and audited 247 packages in 9s
remote:
remote:        16 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:
remote:        > vk2discord@2.1.8 prebuild
remote:        > node ./scripts/buildInit.mjs
remote:
remote:
remote:        > vk2discord@2.1.8 build
remote:        > tsc && node ./scripts/cleanUpBuild.mjs
remote:
remote:        Version 4.3.5
remote:        Syntax:   tsc [options] [file...]
remote:
remote:        Examples: tsc hello.ts
remote:                  tsc --outFile file.js file.ts
remote:                  tsc @args.txt
remote:                  tsc --build tsconfig.json
remote:
remote:        Options:
remote:         -h, --help                                         Print this message.
remote:         -w, --watch                                        Watch input files.
remote:         --pretty                                           Stylize errors and messages using color and context (experimental).
remote:         --all                                              Show all compiler options.
remote:         -v, --version                                      Print the compiler's version.
remote:         --init                                             Initializes a TypeScript project and creates a tsconfig.json file.
remote:         -p FILE OR DIRECTORY, --project FILE OR DIRECTORY  Compile the project given the path to its configuration file, or to a folder with a 'tsconfig.json'.
remote:         -b, --build                                        Build one or more projects and their dependencies, if out of date
remote:         -t VERSION, --target VERSION                       Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'.
remote:         -m KIND, --module KIND                             Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'.
remote:         --lib                                              Specify library files to be included in the compilation.
remote:                                                              'es5' 'es6' 'es2015' 'es7' 'es2016' 'es2017' 'es2018' 'es2019' 'es2020' 'es2021' 'esnext' 'dom' 'dom.iterable' 'webworker' 'webworker.importscripts' 'webworker.iterable' 'scripthost' 'es2015.core' 'es2015.collection' 'es2015.generator' 'es2015.iterable' 'es2015.promise' 'es2015.proxy' 'es2015.reflect' 'es2015.symbol' 'es2015.symbol.wellknown' 'es2016.array.include' 'es2017.object' 'es2017.sharedmemory' 'es2017.string' 'es2017.intl' 'es2017.typedarrays' 'es2018.asyncgenerator' 'es2018.asynciterable' 'es2018.intl' 'es2018.promise' 'es2018.regexp' 'es2019.array' 'es2019.object' 'es2019.string' 'es2019.symbol' 'es2020.bigint' 'es2020.promise' 'es2020.sharedmemory' 'es2020.string' 'es2020.symbol.wellknown' 'es2020.intl' 'es2021.promise' 'es2021.string' 'es2021.weakref' 'esnext.array' 'esnext.symbol' 'esnext.asynciterable' 'esnext.intl' 'esnext.bigint' 'esnext.string' 'esnext.promise' 'esnext.weakref'
remote:         --allowJs                                          Allow javascript files to be compiled.
remote:         --jsx KIND                                         Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'.
remote:         -d, --declaration                                  Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.
remote:         --declarationMap                                   Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file.
remote:         --sourceMap                                        Generates corresponding '.map' file.
remote:         --outFile FILE                                     Concatenate and emit output to single file.
remote:         --outDir DIRECTORY                                 Redirect output structure to the directory.
remote:         --removeComments                                   Do not emit comments to output.
remote:         --noEmit                                           Do not emit outputs.
remote:         --strict                                           Enable all strict type-checking options.
remote:         --noImplicitAny                                    Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
remote:         --strictNullChecks                                 Enable strict null checks.
remote:         --strictFunctionTypes                              Enable strict checking of function types.
remote:         --strictBindCallApply                              Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions.
remote:         --strictPropertyInitialization                     Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes.
remote:         --noImplicitThis                                   Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type.
remote:         --alwaysStrict                                     Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file.
remote:         --noUnusedLocals                                   Report errors on unused locals.
remote:         --noUnusedParameters                               Report errors on unused parameters.
remote:         --noImplicitReturns                                Report error when not all code paths in function return a value.
remote:         --noFallthroughCasesInSwitch                       Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement.
remote:         --types                                            Type declaration files to be included in compilation.
remote:         --esModuleInterop                                  Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'.
remote:         @<file>                                            Insert command line options and files from a file.
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to st-news-bot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/st-news-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/st-news-bot.git'
```

Для этого я скачал их официальное приложение "Heroku CLI" и, следуя инструкции, пытаюсь создать сборку, заранее включив в настройках проекта функцию "Add buildpack", где в качестве сборки выбираю "nodejs"

Инструкция от "Heroku":
[image: Инструкция от Heroku]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте в package.json заменить `"node": ">=15.0.0"` на `"node": "16.x"`

Comment: решение расписал ниже

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел детальнее логи, почитал документацию Heroku, открыл package.json и обнаружил, что мой бот уже пытается создать свою сборку
Я удалил строчку, отвечающую за это в "package.json" вот здесь:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && node ./scripts/cleanUpBuild.mjs",
  },
```

После этого действия сборка нормально сгенерировалась и прекрасно работает